# Why is size of 0 is shown as 4?

Tags: c, integer, sizeof

I understand the `sizeof` operator, but could not understand the background of `sizeof(0)` producing 4 in the following program

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

printf("%d \n",sizeof(0));

return 1;

}
```

Output: 4

Comment: If you didn't expect a 4, what did you expect then? And why?

Comment: Why is the `return 1;` there? What's the fun that i'm missing?

Comment: You might like to know that `sizeof 'a'` is also `4`. The `'a'` might be a character but it is not a `char`.

Answer (score 7):

`sizeof` returns the size of the supplied type, not the *value*.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.3.4, (*emphasis mine*)

> The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an
>   expression or the parenthesized name of a type. **The size is determined from the type of
>   the operand.** [...]

Now, coming to type, `0`, on it's own, is an integer constant.

So, `sizeof(0)` is the same as `sizeof(int)`, on your platform.

That said, `sizeof` produces a `size_t`, so you should use `%zu` format specifier to print that.

Answer (score 0):

0 is an integer and sizeof gives the memory size which is 4 bytes(int)